# SQL to JSON converts my int to string

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have this in my PHP.

```
$sql="select * from defaulttime";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $row_set[] = $row;


}
echo trim(json_encode($row_set));
```

In my SQL some columns are Integer. but in JSON it shows as String.
can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

when I run the PHP, I get the below results. (Note Hour and Minute should be Integers)

```
[{"name":"Test","Hour": "6" ,"Minute":"45"}],
```

I want it to show string as string and Int as Int.

```
{"name":"Test","Hour": 6 ,"Minute":45}
```

Comment: PHP docs on [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) : _Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows in resultset._

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option in order to get numerics value,

look here: https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/php-returning-numeric-values-in-json

```
echo trim(json_encode($row_set,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,

I got it working by using this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $row_set[] = $row;


}

$json=json_encode($row_set,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $json;
```